# Can a pointer point to a struct of item of list of order

Tags: c, data-structures, function-pointers

```
typedef struct item
{
    char itemName[32];
    float price;
    int quantity;
}ITEM;
typedef struct list
{
    void* item[5];
    int (*compare)(void*, void*);
    int length;
}LIST;
typedef struct order 
{
    int orderId;
    float orderTotal;
    LIST* orderItems;
    int length;
} ORDER;
int compareItemPrice(void* p1, void* p2){
    ITEM* p = (ITEM*)p1;
    ITEM* q = (ITEM*)p2;
    if(p->price>q->price)
    {
        return 1;
    } else if(p->price<q->price)
    {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Code above is my structures and function wrote in C. When I implement code below, it showed me errors. The errors was all about ITEM* p which was incomplete definition of struct list.

```
ITEM* getExpensiveItem(ORDER* o){   // Maximum item price
    ITEM* p = o->orderItems->item;
    ITEM* expensiveItem = p;
    for(int i=1; i<o->orderItems->length-1; i++)
    {
        if(compareItemPrice(p, (p+i)) < 0)
        {
            expensiveItem = p+i;
        }
    }
    return expensiveItem;
}
```

Comment: "When I implement code below, it showed me errors." What are the exact error strings you see?

Comment: Try: `struct item` ==> `typedef struct item` (in multiple places)

Comment: the error was "order.c:60:28: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct list'"
    ITEM* p = o->orderItems->item;

Comment: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct list'

Comment: @ZhimingLi Please notice that you should **not** make significant changes to your code once an answer has been posted. The reason is that the answers may become meaningless if they refer to something in your original code that you later changed with an edit.

Comment: @CinCout the error was "order.c:60:28: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct list'"

Comment: @4386427 Got that, I will make it better when posting next question. Thanks.

Comment: Your edit introduced new errors: `type struct item` that is no valid syntax. Try `typedef` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Code like

```
struct a
{
    int i;
} A;
```

will give a variable `A` that you can use like

```
A.i = 42;
```

However, it seems that you really are trying to create a new type. So try:

```
typedef struct a   // Notice the "typedef" in start of line
{
    int i;
} A;
```

That will give a a type `A` that can be used like:

```
A var;
A* pVar;
var.i = 42;
pVar = &var;
....
```

Also notice that your `struct order` uses the type `LIST`. So `LIST` must be declared before `struct order`. Further, the type `CUSTOMER` must also be declared which it currently isn't.

So your code should probably be like:

```
#define N 42  // Made this up as it isn't in your code

typedef struct customer  // Made this up as it isn't in your code
{
    int x;  
} CUSTOMER;

typedef struct list
{
    void* item[N];
    int (*compare)(void*, void*);
    int length;
}LIST;

typedef struct order
{
    int orderId;
    float orderTotal;
    LIST* orderItems;
    CUSTOMER* customer;
    int length;
} ORDER;

typedef struct item
{
    char itemName[32];
    float price;
    int quantity;
}ITEM;
```

Also notice that this line has a problem:

```
ITEM* p = o->orderItems->item;
```

The type of `o->orderItems->item` is **array of void pointer** due to `void* item[N];` in `struct list`. In other words: You are trying to assign an array of pointer to a single pointer. I'm not really sure what you want to do but maybe like:

```
ITEM* p = o->orderItems->item[0];
```

Comment: yeah! Thank you, I edited. But the error block seems still incorrect.

Comment: Edited. Thank you.

Comment: I want to get expensive item. I tried `ITEM* p = (ITEM*) o->orderItems->item;`